# Java code that finds all factors of an interger inputted by a user using while loops

Tags: java, while-loop, factors

So currently, I am working on a piece of code that will determine whether or not an integer is a prime number or not, and that works perfectly fine since I have tested it multiple times using different prime and non-prime integers. Now, I have to wrap it up by being able to list out all factors of any given integer and I just simply don't know what to do. Down below is my current program without the factors part that I need. I don't know where to start since I am not particularly good with "while loops" as we just learned about them today.

This is what I have to do, "The program should give the output of all factors of the integer using appropriate formatting so it the factors are clear.
It should output “The factors of (input) are:”
If the only factors of the integer input are 1 and itself, the program should state: “This is a prime number!” and if it is not
a prime number print nothing."

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
 import java.util.*;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the number that you have chosen?");
    int num = console.nextInt();
    int div = 2;
    boolean run = false;
    System.out.println("The factors of " + num + " are:");
    while (div <= Math.sqrt(num)) {
        if (num % div == 0) {
            System.out.println(div + " , " + num/div);
            div++;
            run = true;
        } else {
            div++;
        }
    }
    if (run == false) {
        System.out.print("This is a prime number!");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: isn't the code already doing that? ran it locally and it is giving me the factors or showing me the prime number.

Comment: I think I am stupid. Lol. You are 100% right. I'm sorry

Comment: if the user types 72, do they want “2,3” or “2,2,2,3,3”, or “2,3,8,9”.   Always ensure you have unambiguous requirements before starting any programming task 

Comment: haha don't beat yourself up @UptownBongo9454

Comment: It was never specified. So I don't know

Comment: @UptownBongo9454 If the question is solved, please accept an answer so that other users can find a solution quick.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you can use this:

```
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = console.nextInt();
    int factor = 1;
    while(factor<=num) {
        if(num%factor==0) {
            System.out.println("Found factor: "+factor);
        }
        factor++;
    }
    console.close();
```

**So what does it do?**

What you want to do is loop through every single number from 1 all the way to the number. This is illustrated from the statement in the while loop `while(factor<=num)`.

To check whether it is a factor, we can use the statement `if(num%factor==0)`. What does this mean? `%` means modulus, and basically it returns the remainder after you divide a number by another number. If the remainder is 0, we know it is a factor (it can divide successfully. If you don't know what a factor is, I recommend you study mathematics first).

We then increment `factor` by 1 each time, and check every number smaller than the user input, since there is no use of checking larger numbers (a number is never a factor of another if it is larger).

**Test Run**

```
10
Found factor: 1
Found factor: 2
Found factor: 5
Found factor: 10
```

If you want to implement prime number verification, you can do:

```
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = console.nextInt();
    int factor = 1;
    int factors=0;
    while(factor<=num) {
        if(num%factor==0) {
            System.out.println("Found factor: "+factor);
            factors++;
        }
        factor++;
    }
    if(factors==2) {
        System.out.println("This is a prime number!");
    }
    console.close();
```

**FINAL VERSION** (according to your requirements)

```
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = console.nextInt();
    int factor = 1;
    int factors=0;
    System.out.print("The factors of "+num+" are: ");
    while(factor<=num) {
        if(num%factor==0) {
            System.out.print(factor+" ");
            factors++;
        }
        factor++;
    }
    if(factors==2) {
        System.out.println("This is a prime number!");
    }
    console.close();
```

**Test Case**

```
2
The factors of 2 are: 1 2 
This is a prime number!
```

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean isPrime = true;
for(int i = 2; i <= num/2; i++){
    if(num % i == 0) {
        System.out.println("The factors of " + num + " are:" + i);
        isPrime = false;
    }
}
if(isPrime) {
    System.out.print("This is a prime number!");
}
```

Something I want you to think is why I am running the loop only till num/2 and not till num? Let me know if you can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Change your while loop a bit to store the factors.

```
List<Integer> factors = new Arraylist<>();
int upperLimit = num/2
while (div <= upperLimit) {
  if (num % div == 0) {
    factors.add(div);
  }
}
```

If you do this at the end of the loop, the `factors` variable which is a list will have all the factors fo the numebr in it. Now you can check if there are numbers in the list other than 1 or itself and if so, its not a prime.

Note: Instead of a list you can also have an array if you are not aware if what lists are in java.

Comment: @UptownBongo9454 Please accept the answer that you are using. Thanks

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I just did small changes to your code. This will give the answer in the best time complexity possible.

```
import java.util.*;
 public class myClass{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the number that you have chosen?");
    int num = console.nextInt();
    int div = 2;
    boolean run = false;
    System.out.println("The factors of " + num + " are:");
    System.out.print("1");
    while (div <= Math.sqrt(num)) {
        if (num % div == 0) {
           System.out.print(" , "+div + " , " + num/div);
            div++;
            run = true;
        } else {
            div++;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(" , "+num);
    if (run == false) {
        System.out.print("\nThis is a prime number!");
    }
}
}
```

**Test Cases**

```
What is the number that you have chosen?
The factors of 10 are:
1 , 2 , 5 , 10

What is the number that you have chosen?
The factors of 5 are:
1 , 5
This is a prime number!
```

Hope this helps you out.